# integrating google map in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

on view i have added one more view `mapView_googlemaps`. I have assigned this view to GMSMapView in xib file & for outlet also.

in viewDidLoad I have added below code

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.554863 longitude:73.804679 zoom:12];

    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        mapView_googlemaps = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 455) camera:camera];

    }
    else
    {
        mapView_googlemaps = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367) camera:camera];
    }
    mapView_googlemaps.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_googlemaps.trafficEnabled=YES;
    mapView_googlemaps.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
    mapView_googlemaps.buildingsEnabled=YES;
    mapView_googlemaps.settings.compassButton = YES;
    mapView_googlemaps.settings.myLocationButton=YES;
    mapView_googlemaps.delegate= self;
    mapView_googlemaps.accessibilityElementsHidden=NO;

 [self.view addSubview:mapView_googlemaps];
```

but it giving error first time only when i installs app on iphone & uses for first time. Each first time it gives different error. belows error are ocurred different time but only at first time.

```
[__NSCFArray serverControlledParamsNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ff56a0

[__NSPathstore serverControlledParamsNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15fuy6h9

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSx_PBMutableArray serverControlledParamsNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157ce1a0'

-[OS_tcp_connection_destination serverControlledParamsNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f17aa0

-[__NSCFType serverControlledParamsNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17feef30'
```

I think this error is because of wrong initialization. I am not getting exact error.

Comment: Try commenting out all of the lines which start mapView_googlemaps.xxx = YES / NO and then see if the crash stops. The uncomment until you find the guilty line.